# byte[] base64 to mp3 file

Tags: c#

I have a byte[] in base64 and I would to save it in a mp3 file.

Can you help me please ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "in base64" in this case. Please give more details.

When you've got a byte array, you'd usually just call:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
```

Now if you've got base64 encoded data, that's usually in the form of a *string* - so you'd use

```
byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, binaryData);
```